# Set max value of input based on selection's data-attribute

Tags: jquery, forms

i want to set max value of an input based on the selection.

Following selection is populated from a database, all these values have a `data-max` attribute, i want those values to be set as max in the input field.

For instance, i have the following form:

```
<select size="1" name="options" class="select">
  <option value="30" data-max="40">30</option>
  <option value="31" data-max="22">31</option>
  <option value="32" data-max="4">32</option>
  <option value="33" data-max="400">33</option>
  <option value="34" data-max="36">34</option>
</select>
```

Besides these SELECT option i have an input field where values supposed to be entered which i want to be match with a maximum value that i have stored for each select value.

this is the input:

```
<input type="number" class="qty" name="qty" value="1" min="1" max="100" />
```

UPDATE::

The PHP part is no longer needed, i have added the values an data attribute as `data-max` now the data-max value should be set as max value of input.

How to do this?

Comment: The type of `input` should be `number`.

Comment: Can we see the PHP code?

Comment: We might also need your table structure then. I'm not sure I understood this: `all these values have a max value stored in the same table`.

Comment: Do you have any `max_value` column in `items` tables? That's what I understood with `all these values have a max value stored in the same table` but it doesn't seem very logical (as you would repeat the same value several times).

Comment: The `$rowx["qty"]` is not the value that you can set up as `max` in inputs?

Comment: @XeBii Pasting the `CREATE` query seems to be the best way to do it to me. :) You can have it by exporting the table depending on the tool you're using.

Comment: I don't get what you want. You have only one `<input type="number"`? What is the expected value you want to put in the "max" attribute? Is it 100? Where does it come from? Has lmgonzalves not answered with his edit? (I thought he had understand what you wanted but now I'm not that sure.)

Comment: @caCtus please check the updated question, now there's no need for the PHP, just a jQuery question. thanks for understanding

Comment: I posted my comment after the edit. Could you answer my questions? Isn't lmgonzalves's first answer good?

Comment: @caCtus the value i want for input's max is the `data-max` value from the selected option... @Imgonzalves has answered the question, but instead of options value, it should be data-max value as max in input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $('input[type=number]').attr('max', $(this).find(":selected").data('max'));
});
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/2kzdaLa1/8/

Comment: @Imgonzalves i have updated the fiddle, but the changes i have made doesn't seems to be working... please check https://jsfiddle.net/2kzdaLa1/3/

Comment: @XeBii I update my answer, you need to add `.find(":selected")` to get the selected option. The [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/2kzdaLa1/8/) show it working :)